# C# - Class properties are not in same order

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties, system.reflection

I have a requirement that,

**Case 1:** I have to iterate over all properties of a class and save it in a file. (Say I have to iterate and save *properties* values)

[image]

**Case 2:** Later I need create a type of class and iterate over its properties to add the saved values in the same order. (Say I have to iterate *properties1*
to update the saved values in same order)

But the order of *properties* and *properties1* is different. Why?

[image]

For this purpose, I have used the concept of reflection to iterate over its properties.

**Note:** Screenshots are for easy understanding and not the actual code.

Comment: Could serialize to JSON or XML fits your needs?

Comment: Because that's [mentioned in the remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx): _"The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies"_. Why are you trying to implement your own serialization, while plenty of existing APIs exist that do that pretty well?

Comment: So the underlying question is "can I get away with omitting the Names" and the answer is No. Use JSon.

Comment: @Halex no, that won't work. What if a newer framework version introduces a new property somewhere in between the others? Then all data will be shifted to the wrong property.

Comment: Well, I don't see a way to order elements which can change, you need something to _order_ them with no matter that order. Otherwise, you need to store the names as well, with Json for example.